# recording sound recognize android

Tags: android, audio, media, voice-recognition

I develop an app where the user can record an sound, maybe a clap or other sounds. The android system should save it, since the user delete the command. With that recording sound the user can select any commands that the device maybe show an intent or others. Now my question: Is it possible that when the microphone are on that the device when it hear the recording voice start the intent and when it is possible how can I do that? I think that I maybe do it with `getMaxAmplitude()` but I need an method to decide the length of that amplitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://code.google.com/p/musicg/ may help you.

You can find the demo app in the site.

The features described in the site as follows:

- Clap Api - Detect whether the input audio is a clap
- Whistle Api - Detect whether the input audio is a whistle
- Read PCM WAVE Headers
- Read audio data
- Trim the audio data
- Save the edited audio file
- Read amplitude-time domain data
- Read frequency-time domain data
- Render audio wave form image (Requires Java 2D & Java Image I/O, Android non-compatible)
- Render audio spectrogram image (Requires Java 2D & Java Image I/O, Android non-compatible)